# Work around eval() in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, eval

I am having a problem with my chrome web app that im working on at the moment. The code works find on a normal chrome browser but the Chrome Web Store doesn't like my code:

> Refused to evaluate script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Here is the one of the sections in my code that contains an eval():

```
function checkTimeToSinglePeriod(p) {
console.log("Check time for Period " + p + "...");
var TempBHour = "period" + p + ".bhour";
TempBHour = eval(TempBHour);
var TempBMin = "period" + p + ".bmin";
TempBMin = eval(TempBMin);
var TempEHour = "period" + p + ".ehour";
TempEHour = eval(TempEHour);
var TempEMin = "period" + p + ".emin";
TempEMin = eval(TempEMin);
}
```

This function is called from a for loop that passes through "p" so it cycles through my objects: period1.bhour, period2.bhour, etc.
The Temp variables (TempEmin, TempEHour, etc.) produce the value of period1.ehour which might be something like 14, instead of a string like "period1.ehour"
I also have a section in my code that uses eval() to switch the strings created to an array name:

```
for (d = 1; d < 8; d++) { //Loop through days
    for (l = 1; l < 8; l++) { //loop through lessons
        itemToSave = "D" + d + "L" + l;
        arrayToSave = "periodsArray" + d + "[" + (l - 1) + "]";
        localStorage.setItem(itemToSave, eval(arrayToSave));
        console.log(itemToSave + " | Saved");
    }
}
```

In here the itemToSave is the localStorage key and the arrayToSave is the array in my code:
periodsArray1[], periodsArray2[], etc.
So can anyone help me work around not using eval()?
Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using dynamic naming of variables, use dynamic naming of properties in an object, or arrays.

Using an object, you would access `periods['period' + p].bhour` instead of `eval('period'+p+'.bhour')`.

If you use an array, you would access `period[p-1].bhour` instead of `eval('period'+p+'.bhour')`.